# Meteor.user() not reactive at Meteor.users.remove

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Currently I am working on a function so that a user can delete his or her own account. I am using `react-meteor-data` to retrieve the user object reactively.

By now I can successfully remove the user from the user collection when invoking my method on the server, but the `Meteor.user()` object on the client is not reactive anymore after deleting the user. Are there any steps I have to care about ? I was thinking I can do it this way:

1. User deletes his/her own account.
2. User gets deleted in the user collection and will be logged out / or that the `Meteor.user()` is reactive after removing the user

What I did so far:

**Container**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import AccountDetail from "../components/user/AccountDetail.component.jsx";

export default EventDetailContainer = createContainer(({ id }) => {
    const user = Meteor.user();
    const selfDelete = () => {
        Meteor.call("selfDelete", error => {
            if (!error) {
                console.log("Success self delete");
            } else {
                console.log("fail self delete");

            }
        });
    }
    return {
        user,
        selfDelete
    };
}, AccountDetail);
```

**Server Method**

```
  Meteor.methods({
        selfDelete() {
            console.log(this.userId);
            try {
                Meteor.users.remove(this.userId);
            } catch (e) {
                throw new Meteor.Error('self-delete', 'Failed to remove yourself');
            }
        }
    });
```

So after `selfDelete()` is called the user gets deleted from the collection, but on the client side `Meteor.user()` is not updated anymore.

Maybe someone knows why this is the case, or maybe you know a better method to let users delete their own account.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const user = Meteor.user();
```

to

```
const user = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId());
```

this makes user depend on the collection and the in build Tracker to rerun the function in your react container. Comment if not working as expected. Works on my containers fine.

Edit: forgot to say, that you need to subscribe and publish Meteor.users in the container in order to make this work. SO your complete code would be:

```
//server
Meteor.publish("myuserssub", function(filter){
    if (filter._id !== this.userId)
        throw new Error("not permitted");
    return Meteor.users.find(filter);
});

//client
const userSub = Meteor.subscribe("myuserssub");
const user = userSub ? Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.user()._id}) : null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your approach, but unfortunately it doesn't work. If I remove the user from the collection, it seems that my whole client side got stuck. With 'meteor toys' the user is still logged in and the subscription is also not updating..

Comment: what happens if you remove the meteor toys package (which is not intended to be used in prod, so just to check if interfereing)?

Comment: Problem still exists. I do not understand why just Meteor.user() is not reactive to the collection.

Comment: Oh I just see something, in your code: `Meteor.users.remove(this.userId);` can you console log it, wether it returns true or false? It does not necessariy throw an error on fail but just return false or undefined or something.

Comment: It returns the user._id and '1'. So the user definitely gets deleted but only the client is not updating accordingly. If I reload the page, I am logged out and can't log in again.

Comment: Maybe one thing to mention. If I delete the user, my "Success self delete" on the client is never printed out, despite the user gets deleted. And the Meteor.user() Object only contains '_id' on the client after deleting.

Comment: Then you could use this "fact" and call logout if the user object contains only an _id and nothing else, such as name or email, which is definitively necessary for logged in users. After the logout the user should not be able to log in again.

Comment: I can not call Meteor.logout() anymore after I deleted the user from the collection. If I call it nothing happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148121/discussion-between-jankapunkt-and-grahan).